# Convertidor Binary to BCD

Tags: vhdl

Because not store in BCD1 num_bin me ? This would correct syntax ?

Functional description

The operation must be as follows:

1. An activation of the reset will reset all internal registers , and pending the start circuit
   a conversion. It will also put an end to '0'.
2. When you start = ' 1' conversion starts . The first step is to store the value there
   in num_bin in an internal register .
3. Later will scroll the bits of this register on a second record
   contain the number in BCD format ( in our case, as we have four digit registration It is 16 bits). The operation is synchronous with the rising edge of the clock.

Code:

```
entity bin2bcd is
  Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
         reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
         inicio : in  STD_LOGIC;
         num_bin : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);
         und : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
         dec : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
         cen : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
         mil : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
         fin : out  STD_LOGIC);
end bin2bcd;

architecture Behavioral of bin2bcd is
  signal bcd1: std_logic_vector (12 downto 0);  
  signal bcd2: std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

begin

  P1: process(reset,clk)   
  begin

    if reset = '1' then
      --fin <= '0';
      bcd1 <= (others => '0');   -- registres to 0
      bcd2 <= (others => '0');   -- registres to 0

    elsif rising_edge(clk) then


      if inicio = '1' then  
        bcd1 <= num_bin; 


        if bcd2(3 downto 0) > "0100" then    -- if >4
          bcd2(3 downto 0) <= bcd2(3 downto 0) or "0011";
        end if;

        if bcd2(7 downto 4) > "0100" then -- if >4
          bcd2(7 downto 4) <= bcd2(7 downto 4) or "0011";
        end if;

        if bcd2(11 downto 8) > "100" then   -- if >4
          bcd2(11 downto 8) <= bcd2(11 downto 8) or "0011";
        end if;

        if bcd2(15 downto 12) > "0100" then      -- if >4
          bcd2(15 downto 12) <= bcd2(15 downto 12) or "0011";
        end if;

        for i in 0 to 12 loop
          bcd2 <= bcd2(14 downto 0) & num_bin(12);
          bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';

          --fin <= '1';
        end loop;

        und <= bcd2 (3 downto 0);   -- unidades
        dec <= bcd2 (7 downto 4);   -- decenas
        cen <= bcd2 (11 downto 8);  -- centenas
        mil <= bcd2 (15 downto 12); -- millares


      end if;
    end if;
  end process P1;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  What are you having problems with?

Comment: The problem I have is when you pretend to test_bench me num_bin value is not stored in bcd1 and also makes me very well the conversion and save it in bcd2

Comment: Your wording is not very clear, but I think I see the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I have is when you pretend to test_bench me num_bin value is not stored in bcd1 and also makes me very well the conversion and save it in bcd2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your for-loop, combined with the fact that you're assigning `bcd1` earlier in the process. You seem to be intending to create a shift register, but that's not what the code you wrote actually does.

In VHDL, signals assigned in processes do not change value immediately - the assignment is scheduled for the end of the process (or any `wait`, in processes that have `wait` statements, though these are non-synthesizable).

Because of this, if your process "executes" multiple assignments to the same signal in the same process, later assignments override earlier assignments, and only the last assignment is what actually takes effect. So, since you have:

```
bcd1 <= num_bin;

...

for i in 0 to 12 loop
  bcd2 <= bcd2(14 downto 0) & num_bin(12);
  bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
end loop;
```

the initial assignment will be overridden by the assignments in the for-loop, so you're never loading `bcd1` with any value.

You also have a second problem, which is that your for-loop won't shift the register as you intend. A for-loop in a clocked process gets unrolled for *every* execution of the process, so this:

```
for i in 0 to 12 loop
  bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
end loop;
```

is equivalent to:

```
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
bcd1 <= bcd1(11 downto 0) & '0';
```

But, as I said before, since only the last assignment is the one that affects the signal, you're just shifting it once.

You probably meant to do:

```
      if inicio = '1' then  
        bcd1 <= num_bin; 
      else
        -- rest of your code goes here
```

That `else` is required so that the initial loading of `bcd1` is not overridden by the later logic. You also need to fix your for-loop. Your algorithm may have multiple other problems, but this is the first one you need to deal with.

Comment: If I do this , I still can not detect when a number greater than 5 will add 3 .

Comment: Why can you not detect this? What exactly is not working? Also, the OR in your code does not necessarily add 3. If you want to truly add 3, you will need to use an add operation.

Comment: What does is that when I have a value greater than 5 on any position BCD2 not add me 3

On the other hand, if I remove and put OR + gives me error

Comment: the number Bynary 1101100001 en the program, BCD is: 0-1-11-1 (error)

Comment: Because `"0101"` is 5, which is greater than 4, but `"0101" or "0011"` is `"0111"`, which is 7. 7 is not 5 + 3. If you need help doing numeric operations, that's a separate issue. You asked why `bcd1` did not get loaded, and the way you're doing your signal assignments is the reason.

Comment: You've seen the code and the image of the simulation ?

Comment: The testbench in TRABAJO1.rar has a component declaration that does not match the unit under test, nor your excerpted code in the question.

Comment: Well, because I 've been modifying it to make it work but no way . That could change to make it work the

Comment: I've had a chance to look at the files you uploaded now, and your waveform snapshot only shows the very end of your sim, when no input signals are changing - this doesn't really tell us anything. I took the liberty of simulating your original code, however, with your testbench, and making the very simple change I recommended at the end of my answer above causes a significant change in behavior. What happened when you tried it?